# Route for /web files in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes

i am using symfony2, i want to test my server for mail functionality so i had create one simple `phpMailer` application and put into `/web` directory of my symfony2 project. Now, when i access that file with `http://example.com/web/mail/index.php` but it give me error,

```
No route found for "GET /web/mail/index.php"
```

i want to use this file as what we can do in `cakephp`. so anyone can help me write route for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your routing configuration

Comment: What do you mean by the application? Is it a controller? Whole script with bootstrapping? Just some PHP file not related to Symfony2 at all?

Comment: sorry, i don't know routing syntax for `\web`  directory, m only know it for controller.

Comment: Configure you web server for that, nothing to do with symfony router.

Comment: You don't put PHP scripts in `/web` ... instead, create a proper route + controller, or it's no use having a symfony 2 project **at all**

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in comments it's not the way you should implement it. But for a quick check you can use `http://example.com/mail/index.php` without `/web` directory in URL, 'cause web directory is usually configured as a root server's configuration.